# Infix to Postfix Converter with parenthesis

Tags: java, calculator, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I'm currently doing an infixToPostfix converter to be used in a calculator assignment. My problem is with that the output seems to show parenthesis when it shouldn't have. I'm stuck with this. Can someone help my out? Thanks.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;

class infixToPostfix{

    Stack<String> stack;
    ArrayList<String> operators;

    String postFix;

    int[] operand = {-1, -1, 1};
    int[] plusorminus = {1,2,-1};
    int[] timesordivide = {3,4,-1};
    int[] raiseto = {6,5,-1};
    int[] openparenthesis = {-1,0,-1};

    public infixToPostfix(String infix) {

        stack = new Stack<String>();
        operators = new ArrayList<String>();

        operators.add("+");
        operators.add("-");
        operators.add("x");
        operators.add("/");
        operators.add("^");
        operators.add("(");
        operators.add(")");

        postFix = new String();

        while(infix.length() > 1){

            String operand = new String();
            String operator = new String();

            if(!operators.contains(infix.substring(0, 1))){
                while(!operators.contains(infix.substring(0, 1)) && !infix.isEmpty()){
                    operand = infix.substring(0,1);
                    infix = infix.substring(1);
                }
                postFix = postFix + operand;
            }
            else if(operators.get(5).equals(infix.substring(0, 1))){
                stack.push(infix.substring(0, 1));
                infix = infix.substring(1);
            }
            else if(operators.get(6).equals(infix.substring(0, 1))){
                while(!stack.peek().equals("(")){
                    postFix = postFix + stack.pop();
                }
                stack.pop();
                infix = infix.substring(1);
            }
            else{
                operator = infix.substring(0,1);

                int[] current = getICPandISP(operator);

                if(!stack.isEmpty()){
                    int[] top = getICPandISP(stack.peek());
                    while(current[0] < top[1] && !stack.isEmpty()){
                        postFix = postFix + stack.pop();
                        if(!stack.isEmpty())
                            top = getICPandISP(stack.peek());
                    }
                }
                stack.push(operator);
                infix = infix.substring(1);
            }
        }
        postFix = postFix + infix;

        while(!stack.isEmpty()){
            postFix = postFix + stack.pop();
        }
    }

    public String toString(){
        return postFix;
    }

    private int[] getICPandISP(String operator){
        if(operator.equals("+") || operator.equals("-")){
            return plusorminus;
        }
        else if(operator.equals("x") || operator.equals("/")){
            return timesordivide;
        }
        else if(operator.equals("^")){
            return raiseto;
        }
        else{
            return openparenthesis;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        infixToPostfix convert = new infixToPostfix("A+B/C-(A/D)*(A+(C-E^F))");
        System.out.println(convert);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is like the fourth question this week about converting infix to postfix. There must be some class that just assigned that, in which nobody really knows how to program yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thre are two minor bugs in the code. First, you are skipping the last character in the expression - which, as it turns out, is a right parenthesis:

```
while(infix.length() > 1){ //should be infix.length() > 0
    // ....
}
```

Second, your code used `'x'` as the multiplication operator, while your expression uses `'*'`.